# What does long-term relative frequency mean?

Tags: statistics

I'm reading an introductory statistics textbook and it mentioned this:

"The probability of any outcome is the **long-term relative frequency** of that outcome. Probabilities are between zero and one, inclusive(that is, zero and one and all numbers between these values). P(A) = 0 means the event A can never happen. P(A) = 1 means the event A always happens"

Comment: "long-term" means more or less what it does in regular English. Are you unfamiliar with "relative frequency", or is it the combination of these two terms that you don't understand? Also note that the book is lying to you. Probability $0$ and $1$ are not strict mathematical guarantees that the respective events will never happen. It just means that the event is very, _very_ (un)likely.

Comment: I'm familiar with relative frequency, just haven't seen it used with long-term before.

Comment: Also, it's the combination of these two terms that I don't understand.